# CSS for star ratings via FontAwesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've tried a few variations of CSS star ratings via different methods, and am trying to implement the following via FontAwesome rather than using a sprite. I want to be able to include half stars ideally, but this is where the example below is failing. This is what I've tried so far. I can't get the half / partial star to work correctly here. Any pointers greatly appreciated!

```css
.score {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.score-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 19px;
}

.score .stars-active {
  color: #EEBD01;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
}

.score .stars-inactive {
  color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-text-stroke: initial;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:88%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:50%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:100%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:0%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt at using half/partial stars. Also link any documentation making you believe your attempt should work as you expect it.

Comment: Sorry, missed a z-indez rule in the snippet - there now, and so in the first example I have 88% width, which should represent 4.5 stars, but this (logically) makes the final star drop down and therefore the half star isn't shown. My issue is how to manipulate the overlaid elements correctly.

Comment: You know that fa-star-half-o exists, right? I don’t see any reference to that in your code anywhere and think it would help you a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The overflow:hidden needs to be on 'stars-active' (the sized element) instead of 'score-wrap' (which never overflows.)   You can use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the stars from wrapping to the next line within the hidden-overflow container.

```css
.score {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.score-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 19px;
}

.score .stars-active {
  color: #EEBD01;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.score .stars-inactive {
  color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-text-stroke: initial;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:88%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:50%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:100%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>

<span class="score">
    <div class="score-wrap">
        <span class="stars-active" style="width:0%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
<span class="stars-inactive">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, one small glitch I'm wrangling with here is that the spaces between the stars are not accounted for in the width calculation, so e.g a width set to 90% should equal 4.5 stars, but in fact it's only showing just a little more than 4 stars as active. Is there a neat way to account for the spacing (which I'd like to keep) in the calculation? I've tried playing around with padding etc but to no avail

Comment: I think if you included padding before the first star and after the last star by the same amount, you could get the numbers to come out even; but it may be easier to just measure it out and hardcode those percentages. With the current design the half-stars seem to be at 8%, 29%, 50%, 71%, and 92%.

Comment: Great font awesome based star rating you got there.

Answer (score 11):

I found this solution by Paales here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/717

I think it's an elegant solution. It looks comparable to your code because the full stars overlap the empty stars and by using `overflow: hidden` and `position: absolute`. Now you can set the width of the full stars and show partly filled stars. If you want to show half stars you could change the width of the absolute positioned element with 10% increments.

```css
.rating-box {
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display:inline-block;
  color: #F68127;
}
.rating-box:before{
    content: "\f006 \f006 \f006 \f006 \f006";
  }
.rating-box .rating {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    color: #F68127;
  }
  .rating-box .rating:before {
      content: "\f005 \f005 \f005 \f005 \f005";
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="rating-box">
    <div class="rating" style="width:30%;"></div>
</div>
```

PS: Daniel Beck already gave you the answer about the mistake you made regarding `white-space: no-wrap`, so I suggest accepting that answer. I just wanted to share this solution because I think it is a very nice alternate approach.

Comment: This doesn't work consistently on all browsers (with newer versions of FA 5.12.1). I have 2 machines running the same version of chrome (80) and one looks good and the other just shows up as squares. (https://jsfiddle.net/MenaceSan/cp2q9wy3/). iOS browser shows just squres as well. I reverted to the 4.7 version of FA and it looks good.

Comment: @Menace The link to the FA stylesheet throws a 404 in your JSFiddle.

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution of all with minimum lines of code. You can check out my solution for FontAwesome 5 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800136/6908282

Answer (score 2):

below is the Font Awesome 5 version of [@Rob's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343426/6908282):

We can use `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: xxx;` to switch between solid and outline

You can play around with the code at the [following link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/css-rating?file=style.css).

```css
/* rating box with fontawesome 5 inspired from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343426/6908282*/

.rating-box {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 3em; /* comment/edit this to change size */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #F68127;
}

.rating-box:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f005 \f005 \f005 \f005 \f005";
}

.rating-box .rating {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #F68127;
}

.rating-box .rating:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f005 \f005 \f005 \f005 \f005";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="rating-box">
  <div class="rating" style="width:52%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find myself doing with two sets of stars styles solid and regular. Solid set declared first to have higher z-index and overlapped Regular sets of stars controlled by hidden, nowrap and width.

```css
.stars-rating {
 position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.stars-rating .stars-score {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              overflow: hidden;
              width: 20%;
              white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
      <div class="stars-rating">
       <div class="stars-score" style="width: 20%">
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
       </div>
    <div class="stars-scale">
     <i class="far fa-star"></i>
     <i class="far fa-star"></i>
     <i class="far fa-star"></i>
     <i class="far fa-star"></i>
     <i class="far fa-star"></i>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, FontAwesome have added half stars to their arsenal. Make sure to include `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the `<head>` section of your page, and then the following will give you the basic structure.

```
    <span class="score">
<div class="score-wrap">
    <span class="stars-active" style="width:88%">
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</span>
</div>
```

If you want the stars to appear bigger, edit `fa fa-star` to be `fa fa-star 3x` where 3x indicates the size, so 3x, 4x, 5x etc. If you would like a different style of star, use `fa-star-o`. The default colour is black, so if you would like to change the colour you can either edit it via CSS or add the colour to the class, i.e `class="fa-star-o bg-light"`

Answer (score 1):

This is very nice, thanks for sharing.
I made the same tweak as Faraz, switching to

```
<i class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

in the stars-active span, and

```
<i class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

in stars-inactive,
as it bothered me that stars above the rating % didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

★★★⯪☆

Just use Unicode characters and then use https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Shapes.html font as it has ⯪ (STAR WITH LEFT HALF BLACK)

```
★★★⯪☆
```

Given the characters (glyphs) above, lets say that ⯪ is rendered as ▯ or some other character that denotes that the glyph is missing from the font.  The way you fix this is that you copy ⯪ (missing glyph) and then
in google type

```
Unicode ⯪
```

(you paste the glyph you are looking for).

From the results you find https://unicode-table.com/en/2BEA/ that says that the character is called "Star with Left Half Black" and that the code is U+2BEA.

Next you take the 2BEA portion of U+2BEA and paste it into the URL below between /char/ and /fontsupport.htm

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2BEA/fontsupport.htm

The URL for your missing character lists all the fonts that contain that character. Now you can click "view" next to each font listed and find the one you like best.
If you find multiple that you like equally well, you can download all of them and then pick the smallest one.

You want to have a .ttf, .woff, and .woff2 version of the font you choose and then you can use it in CSS as follows:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BabelStoneShapes';
  src:  url('/fonts/BabelStoneShapes.woff2')format('woff2'), /* Smallest file, if your browser can use this, it will stop here and not download the rest */
        url('/fonts/BabelStoneShapes.woff')format('woff'),   /* A larger file, if your browser does not understand woff2 */
        url('/fonts/BabelStoneShapes.ttf')format('truetype');/* The largest of the three */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}

div.rating {
  font-family: BabelStoneShapes;
}
```

and then use it in HTML as follows:

```html
<div class="rating">★★★⯪☆</div>
```

Obviously, if Stack Overflow wanted to, they could make their website support virtually all Unicode fonts by using Symbola and updating it each time a new version came out. But they probably never will so in this "Answer" you won't see the half star, but if you follow the example, you will.