# How to show selected rating in the form of filled star in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome, rating-system

I am creating a star based rating system on select of stars and entering comment if click on save button I am saving selected star as int, till this it is working fine but now I want to show the entered rating in the form of filled star. So the rating which I am storing as int in database I want to show it in the form of filled star. I am not using half star.

If I am saving rating value as 4 then I am fetching it from database as Integer value 4. As I am using font-awesome based rating system.

```
            <p>@{ var star = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value); }</p>
                @for (int i = 0; i < star; i++)
                {
                    <select id="Star" name="Star" class="jqStar">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="@i">1</option>
                        <option value="@i">2</option>
                        <option value="@i">3</option>
                        <option value="@i">4</option>
                        <option value="@i">5</option>
                    </select>
                }
```

I want that if rating is 4 then four stars get orange and so on.

Comment: See these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343074/css-for-star-ratings-via-fontawesome.

Comment: @Jasen i want to show filled stars based on the rating value which i am getting from db

Comment: Those answers do that. You'll need to alter the html element attribute values so the css rules can adjust the display.

Comment: What are you stuck on _in particular_, Varun?